# How to give permissions to tomcat instance for accessing other IP directories

Tags: java, eclipse, server, war, tomcat6

My java application is using server location to access to the files in other ip addresses. it is able to access the address when running through eclipse in local but when i am deploying it as a war file it is not able to access to the address 
example:

I am able to locate the file on location:--  158.151.XX.XX\E$\log\xyz.log when running from localhost in eclipse.
But not able to access this file when i am deploying it as war file on tomcat instance.

Is there any thing wrong with the tomcat instance service permissions? how to allow my tomcat instance to have access to this particular ip location? and what if want to add multiple ip location which can be accessed from this instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instance tomcat service i was using did not had permission to access the IP i was trying to locate. For  changing the previous user and giving user and password who has the access : Right click on the service >properties > log on > this account. then give the username and password and apply.

Answer (score 0):

The windows mapping of `....\E$` is a mapping that belongs to you (a windows user), not the tomcat instance.  If you want to serve files from a network location consider setting up a server to serve them.

Comment: But I am able to access that file through windows as I said it is able to accees from localhost